# Angular2 removes "global" query params before Hashbang

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

We have a Angular 2 application where we need to pass in some "deeplink" params using query params into the application. So those params come from outside the angular app.

E.g. the angular app runs on `/xyz/protected/#`
the query params are right before the hashbang (e.g. `/xyz/protected/?deeplinkParam1=test/#`)

What I d like to do is access this param in angular since I need it in the app. But what happens is that angular does a redirect from `/xyz/protected/?deeplinkParam1=test/#` to `/xyz/protected/#` but I have no idea why. I am using Angular 2 routing.

Does someone of you has an idea where I should start investigating?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: use `ActivatedRoute` to get the params in Angular

Comment: queryParams in ActivatedRoute are null. I think that is because of this strange redirect that occurs. Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: okay then handle the params just before you pass it to the component i:e by making use of `Router Resolve`

Comment: my question is why does angular rewrite my URL /xyz/protected?deeplinkParam1=test/# to /xyz/protected/# since that is the root of all my issues. I want this search query (?deeplinkParam1=test) to stay in the url. Any ideas on that?

Comment: because of `Hashlocation stategy`